# Yesod/Persistent best way to store a Ratio

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have been thinking about how to use the benefits of `Ratio` type to not lose precision with calculations like monetary ones, which seems to me a quite reasonable approach.
My question is, what are the good ways to use it with **Persistent**, considering that my backend will be **MySQL**. I have thought about saving it as a varchar, and then passing it to a function to get a Ratio back but I think that might be better approaches.

Comment: Do you plan to do any queries that need to treat the Ratio as a number? Like SELECT * FROM table WHERE amount > 10

Comment: @xnyhps, I think a numerator/denominator approach will work fine for that kind of query. It might be tougher to get the database to sort the results correctly by that value, however.

Comment: @xnyhps I think that for now I don't, but it would be good if I could because, imagine I will use a external tool to create reports, like Jasper Reports, it would be useful for me in several ways to be able to do such comparisons in SQL instead of Java

Comment: If I used varchar, I could use procedures to convert them into numbers, for the purpose of comparing, and also procedures to add, subtract, etc... Don't you think?

Comment: You could also consider using fixed-point numbers, which amount to choosing a single denominator to use for all your values.

Comment: I like @DanielWagner's idea. I think the common practice is to use a fixed-point number, like MySQL's `DECIMAL`, for financial data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a way to store whatever number type you are using as the backend for `Ratio`, you can use the following three functions to "serialize" a `Ratio a` into its constituent `a` values and back:

```
(%) :: Integral a => a -> a -> Ratio a
numerator :: Integral a => Ratio a -> a
denominator :: Integral a => Ratio a -> a
```

Comment: So, I will have a numerator and a denominator which will represent the Ratio type, for instance, I may use Integer type in MySQL. next question, I would like to save it in a single field, I have considered the option of creating a Table and use foreign keys, but I think it will be too much for such thing... How would I store the numerator and denominator in a single field efficiently so?

Comment: @FtheBuilder Personally, I would suggest revisiting the goal of saving it in a single field. What advantage does that actually hold over using two fields?

Comment: I will reconsider, I made that goal because (if I normalize using a table for instance Ratio), there would be a lot of extra joins, even if I just want to print a formatted monetary value onto the screen... But I posted this question exactly to get better approaches. Another thing would be to avoid normalization by using amountNumerator and amountDenominator in each case, which will be a pattern and will not look good

Comment: @FtheBuilder I admit I'm not a database expert; but it's not clear to me why normalization would result in a separate table for fractions rather than just two columns. There's no data redundancy there, unless you expect fractions to be aliased between rows -- in which case you will need a separate table no matter what representation you use.

Comment: You are right. (Maybe it is craziness), but when I am creating things in database, I try to imagine the database as if the columns had no names, so, how much information would I get from the relationships if I couldn't read the name, if I used another table, to represent Ratio, it would be clear that those fields are closely related, and although I would use 1 to 1 relationship, I think that in this case it would be clearer... What do you think, am I crazy?

Comment: @FtheBuilder All columns in a single row are closely related. That is (part of) why they are called relational databases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103546/discussion-between-fthebuilder-and-daniel-wagner).

Comment: `Ratio` is an entity, the stuff inside a (for instance) `Sale` table is related to the `Sale`, but the relationship between these two columns (numerator and denominator) is mindedly related with the `Ratio`, and it will be an entity which may appear on other tables which are also made of a `Ratio`.